# Open netbeans project from a webdav remote

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, webdav

I'm working from the computers of the univertity and I don't know how to open a project from a webdav source, I can't install mount.davfs or davfs2 beacause I'm not sudo.

I tried to make a ln -s to git it as a local folder, but don't work.
I would like to open as when I open it in other programs like with gedit, but I can't access to the Net folders.

Can you help me?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're out of luck. Nautilus can access webdav servers without davfs2 (and no need for sudo) but Netbeans cant access dav:// connections, the files have to be mounted in the filesystem.

Netbeans works well with editing files on davfs2 (i use it all the time), so your best bet is probably to work around the davfs2 restriction with your admins - can you run a VM on the university computer?

Otherwise, if you just want a nice environment to develop web files (eg html/css/js) I suggest you look for an IDE that can open webdav natively. OxygenXML is an excellent tool and can run on linux.